# how avoid the link of the current post in the menu in the sidebar?

Tags: menus, pages

When displaying in the sidebar the menu containing the list of posts, this menu also displays the link to the current post (the current page)

How avoid the link of the current post in this list of posts ?

The files actually used are wp-content/themes/mytheme/sidebar.php, wp-includes/nav-menu-template.php and wp-includes/nav-menu.php.

I use the Navigation Menu Widget.

Comment: which widget do you use to display the menu ?

Comment: Please see th e details I added to my question

Answer (score 1):

you can try this code. the first filter is to customise the widget arguments and the second filter is in the menu generation.

```
add_filter("widget_nav_menu_args", function ($nav_menu_args, $nav_menu, $args, $widget_instance) {

    $post = get_queried_object();

    if (is_a($post, "WP_Post")) {
        $nav_menu_args["remove_post_in_widget"] = $post->ID;
    }


    return $nav_menu_args;

}, 10, 4);


add_filter("wp_nav_menu_objects", function ($sorted_menu_items, $args) {

    if (isset($args->remove_post_in_widget)) {

        foreach ($sorted_menu_items as $index => $item) {

            if ((int) $item->object_id === $args->remove_post_in_widget) {
                unset($sorted_menu_items[$index]);
                break; // stop the loop when the first post is found
            }

        }

    }


    return $sorted_menu_items;

}, 10, 2);
```

Comment: I start with this software. despite my experience in php I have never used hooks.
Can I add this code as is in the widget page?

In the widget's code I have the line:
wp_nav_menu (apply_filters ('widget_nav_menu_args', $ nav_menu_args, $ nav_menu, $ args, $ instance));

Should I touch this line too?

In the navigation menu code, I have the same questions for the second code snippet

Comment: you should not edit the core file of wordpress because your changes will be lost on the next update. to use this hooks, you have to create a new plugin : https://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_a_Plugin